# Saving gif to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, camera, gif

I'm trying to convert a captured video and convert it into a Gif, yet I'm having trouble with saving the converted Gif and saving it into a UIImage object. Ultimatley, I'm trying to use this object to display the gif on UIImageView. Also, note that I'm using NSGIF to convert my videos iinto Gifs. Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tempImageView3: UIImageView!

@IBAction func capture(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !isRecording {
        isRecording = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> () in
            self.cameraButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
            }, completion: nil)

        let outputPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "output.mov"
        let outputFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
        let gifURL: NSURL

        NSGIF.createGIFfromURL(outputFileURL, withFrameCount: 16, delayTime: Float(0.2), loopCount: 0, completion: { (gifURL) -> Void in
            print("output saved \(gifURL)")
        })

        videoFileOutput?.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outputFileURL, recordingDelegate: self)
    } else {
        isRecording = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: { () -> () in
            self.cameraButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
            }, completion: nil)
        cameraButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        videoFileOutput?.stopRecording()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're declaring a constant `let gifURL: NSURL` that is unneeded. Besides the fact it's a constant and not a variable, so no value could be set to it anyway. It's not the same `gifURL` that is in the closure. That's a second definition that would override the first anyway. Delete the `let` line.

Second, I don't know the NSGIF library, but your logic appears backwards. You're calling `NSGIF.createGIFfromURL` with the parameter `outputFileURL` indicating the file to convert, before you call `videoFileOutput?.startRecordingToOutputFileURL` to create that file.

I would think you'd want to do the recording first, and then when you stop recording, convert the file.

So try moving the `createGIFfromURL` call to the `else` block after the line `videoFileOutput?.stopRecording()`.

I've be concerned about that happening on the main thread though. The `videoFileOutput` object appears to have a `delegate`. Does that receive an event once the recording is finished? If so, that would be a better place to convert the file.